# NSarray release

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsarray

If i declare an `NSArray` with `alloc` & `retain` in single sentence then should i release the `NSArray` object twice (i.e. `[arrayObject release]` 2 times) ?

Answer (score 7):

If you are creating an `NSArray` with an `alloc` and a `retain` on the same line then you are probably doing something wrong.

Objects are `alloc`ed with a retain count of +1, so there is no need to call `retain` on it as well.

To answer your question directly; yes, you do have to `release` it twice. Once because you created the object and once because you `retain`ed it. But I would question why you need to retain it an extra time in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to retain it.  You already retain--or take ownership of--an object when you alloc/init.  Revisit the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to release the object for each alloc and each retain. (And you can't alloc an object more than 1 time anyway.)

Comment: That sounds more like a yes than a no.

Comment: @Peter: My bad, I read *with alloc and init on the same line*. I'm going to delete my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
NSArray* arrayObject;
arrayObject = [[NSArray alloc] init];
arrayObject = [[NSArray alloc] init];
...
```

then it just **wrong** code. The latter assignment will cover the old one, which causes a leak. Either use 2 objects, and release **each of them once**:

```
NSArray* arrayObject1, arrayObject2;
arrayObject1 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
arrayObject2 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
...
[arrayObject1 release];
[arrayObject2 release];
```

or release the object **before** another init.

```
NSArray* arrayObject;
arrayObject = [[NSArray alloc] init];
...
[arrayObject release];
arrayObject = [[NSArray alloc] init];
...
[arrayObject release];
```